# Casting generic type with interface constraint

Tags: c#, generics, interface, casting

I have the following classes and interfaces

```
public interface IFoo {}

public class Foo : IFoo {}

public interface IWrapper<T> where T : IFoo {}

public class Wrapper<Foo> : IWrapper<Foo> {}
```

How can I cast `Wrapper<Foo>` to `IWrapper<IFoo>`? An exception is raised when using Cast (InvalidCastException) as I get null when using as.

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE**

Here is a more concrete example:

```
public interface IUser {}

public class User : IUser {}

public interface IUserRepository<T> where T : IUser {}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository<User> {}
```

Now I need to be able to do something like this:

```
 UserRepository up =  new UserRepository();
 IUserRepository<IUser> iup = up as IUserRepository<IUser>;
```

I'm using .net 4.5. Hope this helps.

Comment: Um, you can't - `Wrapper<Foo>` doesn't implement `IWrapper<T>` at all. Also, do you realize that the `Foo` in `Wrapper<Foo>` is actually a new type parameter? It's really unclear what you're trying to do here...

Comment: Yes, I have to ammend the question, but I have Wrapper<Foo> implementing IWrapper<Foo>. Still I don't know how to get IWrapper<IFoo> from Wrapper<Foo>.

Comment: Okay, we still need more information: a) which version of C# are you using; b) how is `T` used within `IWrapper`? (It's possible that you could use generic variance here, but we don't know yet.) And the `Foo` in `Wrapper<Foo>` is *still* a type parameter - did you mean `Wrapper<T> : IWrapper<T>` with an *instance* of `Wrapper<Foo>`? A complete example would help here.

Comment: I’d also like to recommend that you use [static casts rather than runtime casts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3894378/429091) when possible. No point in encountering `InvalidCastException` when the compiler can tell you the cast won’t work without even executing your code ;-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your edit, you actually want:

```
public interface IUserRepository<out T> where T : IUser {}
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository<User> {}
```

then you can do:

```
IUserRepository<IUser> iup = new UserRepository();
```

note you can only add add the `out` modifier to the type parameter `T` if it appears in the output position everywhere in the definition of `IUserRepository` e.g.

```
public interface IUserRepository<out T> where T : IUser
{
    List<T> GetAll();
    T FindById(int userId);
}
```

if it appears anywhere in the input position, such as a method parameter or property setter it will fail to compile:

```
public interface IUserRepository<out T> where T : IUser
{
    void Add(T user);       //fails to compile
}
```

Comment: While technically your answer is correct I doubt that `IUserRepository` can be covariant - unless it is a get-only repository (no adds/updates/deletes).

Comment: @DStanley - See update. The OP should add more information if this isn't sufficient.

Comment: Excellent! The answer pointed me in the right direction. It wasn't at clear what the out keywork was for. I am now starting to get it. Thanks!

Comment: @Lee I agree - I'm just commenting so the next question isn't "How do I add an `Add` method to a covariant interface?" :)

Answer (score 0):

`Wrapper<Foo>` needs to be `Wrapper<IFoo>`. Then you should be able to cast it. And it needs to implement the interface too.

The cast below works... I don't think you can cast an objects generic type parameter to a different type (i.e. `IWrapper<Foo>` to `IWrapper<IFoo>`).

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Wrapper();
    var t = foo as IWrapper<IFoo>;
    t.Dump();       
}


public interface IFoo {}

public class Foo : IFoo {}

public interface IWrapper<T> where T : IFoo {}

public class Wrapper : IWrapper<IFoo> {}
```

Comment: Yes, I have to ammend the question, but I have Wrapper<Foo> implementing IWrapper<Foo>. Still I don't know how to get IWrapper<IFoo> from Wrapper<Foo>

Comment: Why use `as`? The compiler will demote the cast to be runtime rather than compiletime. A direct assignment would be safer and enable the compiler to tell you it won’t work at compiletime…