# How to instantiate a class as the interface that it derives from with constrained generic type parameter

Tags: c#, solid-principles, open-closed-principle, generic-variance

There's the following interface which defines a packet.

```
public interface IPacket
{
    int Size { get; }
}
```

There are two implementations, each with its own additional property.

```
public class FooPacket : IPacket
{
    public int Size => 10;
    public string FooProperty { get; set; }
}

public class BarPacket : IPacket
{
    public int Size => 20;
    public string BarProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The above is library code I have no control over. I want to create a handler for packets

```
public interface IPacketHandler<T> where T : IPacket
{
    void HandlePacket(T packet) ;
}
```

and create two implementations for the concrete packets.

```
public class FooPacketHandler : IPacketHandler<FooPacket>
{
    public void HandlePacket(FooPacket packet) { /* some logic that accesses FooProperty */ }
}

public class BarPacketHandler : IPacketHandler<BarPacket>
{
    public void HandlePacket(BarPacket packet) { /* some logic that accesses BarProperty */ }
}
```

I'd like to inject a list of packet handlers into a class that manages packet handling so that it can be extended in the future with additional packet handlers.

```
public class PacketHandlerManager
{
    public PacketHandlerManager(IEnumerable<IPacketHandler<IPacket>> packetHandlers)
    {

    }
}
```

The trouble I'm having is when creating the injected parameter. I cannot do

```
var packetHandlers = new List<IPacketHandler<IPacket>>
{
    new FooPacketHandler(),
    new BarPacketHandler()
};
```

because I cannot create an instance like so:

```
IPacketHandler<IPacket> packetHandler = new FooPacketHandler();
```

I get the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'FooPacketHandler' to 'IPacketHandler<IPacket>. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

I had a look at a similar question: [Casting generic type with interface constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956407/casting-generic-type-with-interface-constraint). In that question, OP didn't show the members of the interface, only the definition of it from a generics point of view. From what I can see, if my interface didn't use the generic type parameter as an input, I could make it covariant using the `out` keyword, but that doesn't apply here.

How do I achieve making manager adhere to the open-closed principle? Is my only recourse changing the interface definition to

```
public interface IPacketHandler
{
    void HandlePacket(IPacket packet);
}
```

and then casting to a particular packet in the implementation?

Comment: The thing is, a FooPacketHandler *can't* handle any old `IPacket`. It can only handle a FooPacket. It isn't a nice general `IPacketHandler<IPacket>`; it's only a very specific `IPacketHandler<FooPacket>`. The compiler isn't just getting the vapors here, it's telling you *this* thing truly isn't *that* thing.

Answer (score 2):

The core of the issue is that ultimately you would call your handler passing a **concrete** packet (of a concrete type) to it as an argument, even though you hide the argument behind `IPacket`.

Somehow then, trying to call the `HandlePacket( FooPacket )` with `BarPacket` argument would have to fail, the only question is when/where it fails.

As you already noticed, introducing the generic parameter to the packet handler makes it fail in the compile time and there is no easy workaround over it.

Your idea to drop the generic parameter, i.e. to have

```
public interface IPacketHandler
{
   void HandlePacket(IPacket packet);
}
```

is a possible solution. It however pushes the possible failure to the runtime, where you now have to check if a handler is called with inappropriate argument.

What you could also do is to make this runtime check more explicit by introducing a contract for it:

```
public interface IPacketHandler
{
   bool CanHandlePacket(IPacket packet);
   void HandlePacket(IPacket packet);
}
```

This makes it cleaner for the consumer to safely call `HandlePacket` - assuming they get a positive result from calling `CanHandlePacket` before.

For example, a possible naive loop over a list of packets and calling your handlers would become

```
foreach ( var packet in _packets )
  foreach ( var handler in _handlers )
    if ( handler.CanHandlePacket(packet) )
      handler.HandlePacket(packet);
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as how C# uses the [TypeConverter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netcore-3.0)

Comment: You understood my concerns. My idea was to have some kind of static type checking at compile time rather than the method casting an `IPacket` to the concrete type at runtime. Further, what I didn't show in my code is that `IPacket` has a `PacketType` member, and while thinking about ideas, I added a `PacketType HandlesPacketOfType { get; }` member to `IPacketHandler`, which the manager would use, in a similar fashion to your suggestion, to find the appropriate handler. This is not optimal though as you can ignore the helper method and still call the `HandlePacket` with a mismatching type.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with a little bit of reflection.

Firstly, for convenience (and to help *slightly* with type-safety), introduce a "Tag" interface which all your `IPacketHandler<T>` interfaces will implement:

```
public interface IPacketHandlerTag // "Tag" interface.
{
}
```

This is not really necessary, but it means you can use `IEnumerable<IPacketHandlerTag>` instead of `IEnumerable<object>` later on, which does make things a little more obvious.

Then your `IPacketHandler<T>` interface becomes:

```
public interface IPacketHandler<in T> : IPacketHandlerTag where T : IPacket
{
    void HandlePacket(T packet);
}
```

Now you can write a `PacketHandlerManager` that uses reflection to pick out the method to use to handle a packet, and add it to a dictionary like so:

```
public class PacketHandlerManager
{
    public PacketHandlerManager(IEnumerable<IPacketHandlerTag> packetHandlers)
    {
        foreach (var packetHandler in packetHandlers)
        {
            bool appropriateMethodFound = false;
            var handlerType = packetHandler.GetType();
            var allMethods  = handlerType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var method in allMethods.Where(m => m.Name == "HandlePacket"))
            {
                var args = method.GetParameters();

                if (args.Length == 1 && typeof(IPacket).IsAssignableFrom(args[0].ParameterType))
                {
                    _handlers.Add(args[0].ParameterType, item => method.Invoke(packetHandler, new object[]{item}));
                    appropriateMethodFound = true;
                }
            }

            if (!appropriateMethodFound)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No appropriate HandlePacket() method found for type " + handlerType.FullName);
        }
    }

    public void HandlePacket(IPacket packet)
    {
        if (_handlers.TryGetValue(packet.GetType(), out var handler))
        {
            handler(packet);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No handler found for packet type " + packet.GetType().FullName);
        }
    }

    readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<IPacket>> _handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<IPacket>>(); 
}
```

If a packet handler passed to the `PacketHandlerManager` constructor does not implement a method called `HandlePacket` with a single argument that is assignable from `IPacket`, it will throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

For example, attempting to use an instance of the following class would cause the constructor to throw:

```
public class BadPacketHandler: IPacketHandlerTag
{
    public void HandlePacket(string packet)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handling string");
    }
}
```

Now you can call use it thusly:

```
    var packetHandlers = new List<IPacketHandlerTag>
    {
        new FooPacketHandler(),
        new BarPacketHandler()
    };

    var manager = new PacketHandlerManager(packetHandlers);

    var foo = new FooPacket();
    var bar = new BarPacket();
    var baz = new BazPacket();

    manager.HandlePacket(foo);
    manager.HandlePacket(bar);
    manager.HandlePacket(baz);
```

---

Putting it all together into a compilable console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public interface IPacket
    {
        int Size { get; }
    }

    public class FooPacket : IPacket
    {
        public int    Size        => 10;
        public string FooProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class BarPacket : IPacket
    {
        public int    Size        => 20;
        public string BarProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class BazPacket : IPacket
    {
        public int    Size        => 20;
        public string BazProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IPacketHandlerTag // "Tag" interface.
    {
    }

    public interface IPacketHandler<in T> : IPacketHandlerTag where T : IPacket
    {
        void HandlePacket(T packet);
    }

    public class FooPacketHandler : IPacketHandler<FooPacket>
    {
        public void HandlePacket(FooPacket packet)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling FooPacket");
        }
    }

    public class BarPacketHandler : IPacketHandler<BarPacket>
    {
        public void HandlePacket(BarPacket packet)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handling BarPacket");
        }
    }

    public class PacketHandlerManager
    {
        public PacketHandlerManager(IEnumerable<IPacketHandlerTag> packetHandlers)
        {
            foreach (var packetHandler in packetHandlers)
            {
                bool appropriateMethodFound = false;
                var handlerType = packetHandler.GetType();
                var allMethods  = handlerType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                foreach (var method in allMethods.Where(m => m.Name == "HandlePacket"))
                {
                    var args = method.GetParameters();

                    if (args.Length == 1 && typeof(IPacket).IsAssignableFrom(args[0].ParameterType))
                    {
                        _handlers.Add(args[0].ParameterType, item => method.Invoke(packetHandler, new object[]{item}));
                        appropriateMethodFound = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!appropriateMethodFound)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("No appropriate HandlePacket() method found for type " + handlerType.FullName);
            }
        }

        public void HandlePacket(IPacket packet)
        {
            if (_handlers.TryGetValue(packet.GetType(), out var handler))
            {
                handler(packet);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No handler found for packet type " + packet.GetType().FullName);
            }
        }

        readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<IPacket>> _handlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<IPacket>>(); 
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var packetHandlers = new List<IPacketHandlerTag>
            {
                new FooPacketHandler(),
                new BarPacketHandler()
            };

            var manager = new PacketHandlerManager(packetHandlers);

            var foo = new FooPacket();
            var bar = new BarPacket();
            var baz = new BazPacket();

            manager.HandlePacket(foo);
            manager.HandlePacket(bar);
            manager.HandlePacket(baz);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

> Handling FooPacket
>
> Handling BarPacket
>
> No handler found for packet type ConsoleApp1.BazPacket

Comment: This is a possible solution but I can't say I particularly like the `packet.GetType()` call, which you cannot avoid, or the `MethodInfo.Invoke` call, which you could by converting it into a delegate. As I mentioned in another comment, my idea was to avoid runtime type operations altogether, but I guess there's no such solution. It's either this or a packet handler that accepts `IPacket` and then casts it to the concrete type.

Comment: As an aside, I would use the `nameof` operator to check method name equivalence to guard against possible future name changes like `nameof(IPacketHandler<IPacket>.HandlePacket)`.

Comment: This is a very efficient way to implement it, mind - the bulk of the reflection is done in the `PacketHandlerManager` constructor; the actual dispatching requires only an O(1) dictionary lookup and a call to a delegate. This is quite similar to the internals of a dependency-container implementation.

Comment: I understand that _most_ of the reflection is done in the constructor, but there's another one in the `HandlePacket` method, which does a `.GetType()` call everytime a packet comes in. Would you not categorise that as an expensive call?

Comment: @Moss, No, GetType() is an extremely efficient call. Each object has a type pointer, so it's pretty much a simple dereference (the type object itself is created only once and is shared by all instances of a type).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. The solution I ended up with is this, starting with the library code:

```
public enum PacketType
{
    Foo,
    Bar
}

public interface IPacket
{
    PacketType Type { get; }
}

public class FooPacket : IPacket
{
    public PacketType Type => PacketType.Foo;
    public string FooProperty { get; }
}

public class BarPacket : IPacket
{
    public PacketType Type => PacketType.Bar;
    public string BarProperty { get; }
}
```

The above version is a better approximation of the real thing.

```
public interface IPacketHandler
{
    void HandlePacket(IPacket packet);
}

public abstract class PacketHandler<T> : IPacketHandler where T : IPacket
{
    public abstract PacketType HandlesPacketType { get; }

    public void HandlePacket(IPacket packet)
    {
        if (packet is T concretePacket)
        {
            HandlePacket(concretePacket);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void HandlePacket(T packet);
}

public class FooPacketHandler : PacketHandler<FooPacket>
{
    public override PacketType HandlesPacketType => PacketType.Foo;

    protected override void HandlePacket(FooPacket packet) { /* some logic that accesses FooProperty */ }
}

public class BarPacketHandler : PacketHandler<BarPacket>
{
    public override PacketType HandlesPacketType => PacketType.Bar;

    protected override void HandlePacket(BarPacket packet) { /* some logic that accesses BarProperty */ }
}

public class PacketHandlerManager
{
    public PacketHandlerManager(Library library, IEnumerable<IPacketHandler> packetHandlers)
    {
        foreach (var packetHandler in packetHandlers)
        {
            library.Bind(packetHandler.HandlesPacketType, packetHandler.HandlePacket);
        }
    }
}
```

There's some more logic in `PacketHandlerManager` which I've omitted here. `library` dispatches packets to handlers, so I don't have to deal with that explicitly after I register handlers using the `Bind` method.

It's not exactly what I imagined, but it'll do.